# Axios get data from API - React.js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios to get data from an API, I am trying to do something very simple and I have done it before.
I can see on the console that my request was made but I cant output the data or a console.log() message.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://dog-api.kinduff.com/api/facts")
    .then( response => {
        console.log("Facts: ")
        this.setState({DogFact:response.data})
    })
    .catch( err => {
        this.setState({error:err.data.message})
    })
}
```

The response from the api is an object with an array.

```
{facts["fact written here"]}
```

It should be very simple but If I try that:

```
axios.get("https://dog-api.kinduff.com/api/facts")
.then( response => {
    console.log("Facts: ", response) //This wont show up on the console
    this.setState({DogFact:response.facts[0]}) //This wont work.
})
```

I dont really understand what might be wrong.
Could someone maybe help me out?

Comment: Its a cors issue most probably due to which the promise goes into .catch which is why you don't see the console

Comment: You are right. I am getting a network error but there is no other information.
When I check the console I can see the request and the correct response. That is why I got confused.

Comment: 1.if you have control over the backend server then you can set 
"Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "your-website-address.com" or wildcard
"Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"

2.you can use chrome extension [*Allow-Control-Allow-Origin*][1] (but each browser may need to install this plugin to work on it)


  [1]: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line in package.json

```
"proxy": "https://dog-api.kinduff.com/api/"
```

then in your axios call change it to this:

```
axios.get("/facts")
.then( response => {
    console.log("Facts: ", response) 
    this.setState({DogFact:response.facts[0]})
});
```

Comment: So that means that the problem was really CORS and using proxy is a way to overcome it?